# How do I update envisage v3 to envisage v4

Tags: 10.04, python, updates, plugins

I just installed the [envisag](http://code.enthought.com/projects/envisage/documentation.php) 3.x plugin from the Ubuntu Software Center, My question is, how can I update this to envisage 4.x.

I'm using `python 2.6` and `Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package has renamed, Ubuntu Oneric is currently with 4.0.0 for "envisage" and 3.2.0 for "envisagecore":

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-envisage

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-envisagecore

> python-envisage (4.0.0-1) unstable; urgency=low
>
> - New upstream release
> - Rename package to python-envisage -
>     replaces python-envisagecore
>     and python-envisageplugins packages

So basically wait for Ubuntu 11.10 for release, or [try the beta](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot/TechnicalOverview/Beta1).